# Enable/Disable just_audio_background

Tags: just-audio

I use just_audio on two pages in my app.
Page 1 is a normal player, as shown in just_audio.
Page 2 is similar to reels, where I display background images and an audio for each one.
However, on this page, I would not like to enable just_audio_backgroud, which should only work when the user uses page 1.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to enable and disable just_audio_background for specific pages. When I use dispose, the background is closed, but I cannot reinitialize it into a new playlist on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. This is explained in the opening section of the README:

> (just_audio_background) supports the simple use case where an app has a single AudioPlayer instance. If your app has more complex requirements, it is recommended that you instead use the audio_service package directly